# How to record stereo audio with an iPhone 12 only?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, microphone, sound-volume

Is there a way to record stereo audio (without video) using an iPhone 12?
The phone has multiple microphones, and I think records in stereo when making a video using the camera app.

Is there a way to record audio only in stereo without using any additional hardware on the phone?